# Problema al subir archivo con ajax, el php no me reconoce el method "POST"

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

tengo un problema con la subida de archivos al utilizar ajax, cuando hago click en el boton subir, el archivo PHP no me reconoce el method POST y no me obtiene el valor ingresado en ese campo de texto.

este es mi formulario:

```
<form method="POST" action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
            <input type="hidden" name="referencia" id="referencia" class="form-control">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
             <input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" />
        </div>
         <div id="messageupload"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4 pull-right">
            <button type="btn" id="uploadfile" class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> Subir </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Este es mi script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#uploadfile',function(){
            var property = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];
            var form_data = new FormData();
            form_data.append("file",property);
            $.ajax({
                url:'upload.php',
                method:'POST',
                data:form_data,
                contentType:false,
                cache:false,
                processData:false,
                beforeSend:function(){
                    $('#messageupload').html('Loading......');
                },
                success:function(data){
                    $('#messageupload').html(data);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Por favor alguien me puede ayudar.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" id="formmass" action="../update/1" method="POST" role="form" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<input type="hidden" name="referencia" id="referencia" class="form-control">
<input type="file" id="upload" name="upload" accept=".doc,.docx,.pdf" />

<button type="button" id="acciones" class="btn btn-primary mass" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-check"></span> massar
                            </button>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('.modal-footer').on('click', '.add', function() {
    //url: '../store',
    var formData = new FormData($("#formmass")[0]);
    formData.append('id',$('#referencia').val());


    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '../store',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    error: function(jqXHR, text, error){
    toastr.error('Validation error!', 'No se pudo Añadir los datos<br>'+error, {timeOut: 5000});
    },
    success: function(data) {

    }
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: Amigo, lo he tratado de replicar pero nada no funciona.

Comment: vaya a inspeccionar y en la parte de network y console que mensajes le sale

Comment: @marcosalbertosaavedrasanabr no creo que funcione porque ya das por hecho que el formulario tiene un `action` , Yo le quitaría la propiedad y en el javascript le pondría `e.preventDefault()`